# Use Different Usernames for Windows Login and Exchange Email Address

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2013

We have Windows Server environment with Active Directory and Exchange. Exchange is already Integrate with Active Directory and Therefore i have security concern because our user names are public. Email address contain User account name and everyone knows our company user names. I want to use different use name for Exchange and active Directory user login. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The [User-Principal-Name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-userprincipalname) login username will be the same for both.

> This attribute contains the UPN that is an Internet-style login name
> for a user based on the Internet standard [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822). The UPN is shorter
> than the distinguished name and easier to remember. By convention,
> this should map to the user email name.

Although it's the convention, this doesn't have to be the same that is used as a public email address, which is controlled by the [`Proxy-Addresses` attribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-proxyaddresses) and [Email address policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/email-addresses-and-address-books/email-address-policies/email-address-policies?view=exchserver-2019).

In `Proxy-Addresses`, uppercase value `SMTP` indicates the primary SMTP email address which is displayed on outbound mail, e.g. `SMTP:first.last@example.com`, whereas lowercase `smtp:alias@example.com` indicates an alias, a.k.a. *proxy address*.

The `proxyAddresses` attribute is available in *Attribute Editor* tab on *Properties* dialog of the AD user object. However, in *Active Directory Users and Computers*, you must have *View* > *Advanced Features* enabled to see it.

For company wide changes, refer to [Procedures for email address policies in Exchange Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/email-addresses-and-address-books/email-address-policies/eap-procedures?view=exchserver-2019).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the UPN to a different format while keeping the primary email IDs as per your current format. Since UPN is the login ID, the email id which is public and UPN which isn't public, would be different things.

Comment: True, but isn't this just stating the same that's already in my answer, but without the details on how to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Your username is the actual name of the mailbox on the Exchange server. This name was set by your account administrator when your mailbox was created. It could be in the format of firstname.lastname, or name3, and is unique to your mailbox. For example, if your name is John Smith, your username could be john3 or john.smith.

Your primary email address (in our environment, this is also your User Principal Name, or UPN) is associated with your mailbox username. It will also appear in the From field of the messages others receive from your mailbox. You will be able to receive messages using other email addresses, but not send messages from them.

https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000698

Comment: For example my email address is example@abc.com, my computer login name also same. can i change my login to something else?

Comment: The userPrincipalName attribute is the logon name for the user. The attribute consists of a user principal name (UPN), which is the most common logon name for Windows users. Users typically use their UPN to log on to a domain. It can be different from the email address. But it is recommended to be the same.